# Countdown to the end of the HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video, countdown

Can I make a countdown to the end of the HTML5 video?

```
<video id="video" width="400" height="225" preload="auto">
    <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
<div id="countdown">Video ends after <span>XX</span> seconds.</div>
```

I understand that a have to wait for the video load, and then if the video is loaded, need to know the length and run video and coundown.

Comment: you could help with code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Listen to the timeupdate event fired by the video object and update the time remaining.

Something like this should work:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateCountdown);

function updateCountdown() {
    var timeSpan = document.querySelector('#countdown span');
    timeSpan.innerText = video.duration - video.currentTime;
}
```

Comment: and how to automatically start playing when the video loaded?
i tried like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gg3B6/1/
it works but correctly it?

Comment: Just add `autoplay="true"` to your video element. I've updated your fiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gg3B6/2/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you

```
countdown = video.duration - video.currentTime
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) for more details