# Add time left to HTML video

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, countdown

I am trying to see a video using Chrome. In particular, I would like to add some useful commands to it, such as a countdown element. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <script>
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        video.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateCountdown);

        function updateCountdown() {
            var timeSpan = document.querySelector('#countdown');
            timeSpan.innerText = video.duration - video.currentTime;
        }
    </script>
        
</head>
    
    
<body>
    <video id="video" controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="file://..........." type="video/mp4"></video>
    <div style="color:RED;" id="countdown">Video ends after <span id="countdown">xx</span> seconds.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like it to show how much time is left, but it is not working. How can I fix it?

And how can I make it ring every time 5 minutes of the video have passed?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Countdown to the end of the HTML5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491392/countdown-to-the-end-of-the-html5-video)

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I read and used it to try before asking this question, but then I couldn't make my code work

Answer (score 0):

You have not given your video element an id so the getElementById can't find it. There must be some errors on your browser's dev tools console, do you see them?

To time the 5 minutes you could use a setTimeout function and get it to call a function that creates a sound.

Comment: It gives me ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at videos.HTML:6```

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's because you have not given your video element an id. Give it an id="video" as you are looking for the element with that id.

Comment: Can you please update your code in your question to show what you now have.

Comment: What errors are you now seeing in your browser console?

Comment: the same as before, ```videos.HTML:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null```

Comment: The problem now is that your HTML divs have not been loaded when you try to access the video one. Put your JavaScript after the HTML. Best to learn about the onload event for future reference also.

Comment: Great! As I said, get to understand onload event so you are sure things are loaded when you need them for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Create your HTML elements **first** so they are existing when using Javascript to control them.

```
<html>
<head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> </head>
   
<body>
    <video id="myVideo" name="media" controls autoplay>
    <source src="file://..........." type="video/mp4"></video>
    <div style="color:RED;" id="countdown">Video ends after <span id="countNumbers"> xx  </span> seconds.</div>
</body>

<script>
     
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateCountdown, true);
 
    var timeSpan = document.getElementById("countNumbers"); //# was document.querySelector('#countdown'); 

    function updateCountdown() 
    {  timeSpan.innerText = Math.round(vid.duration - vid.currentTime); }

</script>

</html>
```

**(2)** For sound every 5 minutes, remember JS is counting in millisecs (eg 1 second is 1000 ms, so you need a value of `60,000 x 5` to represent 5 mins). So you need logic like the below example.

```
if( video.currentTime >= (lastTime + five_mins) ) 
{ 
    //# update new "lastTime" to start from here onwards
    //alert(" 5 mins have passed ... ");
    lastTime = video.currentTime; 
    soundFile.play; //# play the audio tag by its ID
}
```

PS: Your idea might break if user seeks the video etc, so if you just want a timer that plays a sound every 5 mins regardless  of `.currentTime` then use either `settimeout` or `setinterval`...

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a html countdown and sync it with the *"Video ends after xx seconds"*  text. 
 If that doesnt work then try doing something like Youtube's countdown thing (if you can inspect the element code and find the right code) you can do it!

Comment: Hi! I'm trying, but I don't understand how to do it in the right way.